# Converting Amazon AWS keys for use with SES

Tags: java, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've been attempting to convert my Amazon Web Services IAM key for use with SES and I haven't been able to successfully authenticate with the code that I'm using.

I've taken the [algorithm from the official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html#Obtaining%20Amazon%20SES%20SMTP%20Credentials%20by%20Converting%20AWS%20Credentials) and attempted to convert it to Python.  While I believe that I have done this correctly, this could definitely use a review.

The documentation example code (as it is written in Java) is as follows:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SesSmtpCredentialGenerator {
       private static final String KEY = "AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY"; //  Replace with your AWS Secret Access Key.
       private static final String MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail"; // Used to generate the HMAC signature. Do not modify.
       private static final byte VERSION =  0x02; // Version number. Do not modify.

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              // Create an HMAC-SHA256 key from the raw bytes of the AWS Secret Access Key
              SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");

              try {
                     // Get an HMAC-SHA256 Mac instance and initialize it with the AWS secret access key.
                     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                     mac.init(secretKey);

                     // Compute the HMAC signature on the input data bytes.
                     byte[] rawSignature = mac.doFinal(MESSAGE.getBytes());

                     // Prepend the version number to the signature.
                     byte[] rawSignatureWithVersion = new byte[rawSignature.length + 1];               
                     byte[] versionArray = {VERSION};                
                     System.arraycopy(versionArray, 0, rawSignatureWithVersion, 0, 1);
                     System.arraycopy(rawSignature, 0, rawSignatureWithVersion, 1, rawSignature.length);

                     // To get the final SMTP password, convert the HMAC signature to base 64.
                     String smtpPassword = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(rawSignatureWithVersion);       
                     System.out.println(smtpPassword);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                     System.out.println("Error generating SMTP password: " + ex.getMessage());
              }             
       }
}
```

and here is the code that I have written:

```
def hash_IAM(user_password):
#http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html
    if DEBUG: debug_message("Hashing for IAM to SES values")

    #Pseudocode:
    #encrypted_intent = HmacSha256("SendRawEmail", "AWS Secret Key")
    #encrypted_intent = concat(0x02, encrypted_intent)
    #resultant_password = Base64(encrypted_intent)

    #private static final String KEY = "AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY";
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = user_password

    # private static final String MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail";
    AWS_MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail"

    #private static final byte VERSION =  0x02;
    #see chr(2) below.

    #SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    #Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    #mac.init(secretKey);
    #If I understand correctly, SecretKeySpec is just a vessel for the key and a str that mac.init expects..
    #http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html [(key data), (algorithm)]
    #http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html#init(java.security.Key, java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec)

    #in Python 2, str are bytes
    signature = hmac.new(
        key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        msg=AWS_MESSAGE,
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).digest()

    # Prepend the version number to the signature.
    signature = chr(2) + signature

    # To get the final SMTP password, convert the HMAC signature to base 64.
    signature = base64.b64encode(signature)

    return signature
```

And I've given myself very-open IAM group permissions:

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ses:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm hoping that someone can spot an issue in my code or knows something about the API that I was not able to find via Google searches.

Update: I compiled the Java version and my output matches that of a test string.  Ostensibly, my Python version is correct, but I'm still getting exceptions of type SMTPAuthenticationError.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could it be a mismatch of ascii and utf-8?

Comment: @vraiment I compiled their Java version and ran a string through their and my functions... same output.  I guess it's in how I'm using their API or something on the Amazon end.  I'll post the Java script that I used after I clean it up.